# 1080p Action/Sports Camera Recommendation

Tags: video-camera

I'm looking for an action/sports camera (used for recording while snowboarding/biking etc).

- It should record at 1080p - 60fps but 1080p - 30fps works as well.
- Must have underwater case
- Supports at least 32Gb microSD/SD card.
- Should have the option to also take photos

My budget would be around $150-$200.

If you have any knowledge about some, what it's good to look at, please share it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your needs I've added a few various cameras. All are great choices and meet the specifications the question provided, but it's up to you to decide which one you think fits your needs best.

---

## Sony Action Cam - $115 - $198

I'd recommend Sony's [Action Cam](http://www.sony.com/electronics/actioncam/hdr-as20) line up.

[image: Sony Action Cam]

Sony's Action Cam offers a *wide* variety of features, a quality build, and all at a reasonable price.

Sony offers a wide variety of their Action Cams, but I'll be recommending the [AS2000V](http://amzn.com/B00R1COCVI). The Sony "Action Cam"s can take 1080p @60fps and great 8.8MP photos. It supports 240fps slow-mo, and a great microphone. It supports 60m waterproof. It also has video stabilization with SteadyShot which I've heard *great* things about.

#### Alternatives

I **highly** recommend you take a look at the wide variety of Action Cams, these don't get too expensive and offer many features. An example is the [Sony AS15](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0090EC5MS) which is only $128 on Amazon and offers a similar set of features. Also, be on the lookout for discounts as these frequently go on sale.

> This camera has a lot to offer with it's wide variety of features making it a great choice if you'll be doing some shaky video, low-light filming, or for general use.

## GoPro, $129 - $199

The popular GoPro is a popular choice for a sports and action camera. While price ranges, GoPros have a wide range of accessories and mounts to choose from.

The GoPro I'd recommend is the [**GoPro Hero ~$129**](http://shop.gopro.com/cameras/hero/CHDHA-301.html). If you want, a WiFi equipped model which also offers *slightly* better specs, it's starts at [$199](http://shop.gopro.com/cameras/heroplus/CHDHC-101.html)

[image: GoPro Hero picture]

The GoPro Hero can take 1080p @30fps (60 WiFi model) video, photos can be taken at 5MP (8MP WiFi model), and supports up to a 32GB MicroSD. It's also waterproof up to 40 meters.

#### Alternatives

I've already talked about the HERO with WiFi but the [HERO4](http://shop.gopro.com/hero4/hero4-session/CHDHS-101.html) Session also the same specs as the HERO with WiFi at the same price. The HERO4 though has a much simpler design, which can work great for hobby use but may lack functionality for power-users.

> I'd recommend the GoPro if you'll take advantage of it's wide-array of mounts and accessories

## ISAW, $100 - $189

The **[ISAW EDGE ~$189](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014MO8AOC)** seems to be a perfect fit.

[image: ISAW EDGE Picture]

The ISAW EDGE can take 1080p @60fps, and even 4K. It can take up to a 64GB Micro SD card and can take 16MP stills. It features underwater capabilities up to 40m.

#### Alternatives

The **ISAW Air** runs at 1080p @30fps, takes 12MP photos but requires a case for waterproof (~$25)

The **ISAW WING** runs at 1080p @30fps, takes 12MP photos and features a 40m waterproof housing.

> The ISAW offers well balanced specs at a reasonable price, it has a relatively easy-to-use graphical interface.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed answer. I also looked a bit, compared some stuff with your recommendations and got to this [Polaroid Cube+](http://www.polaroid.com/products/cube-plus-action-camera) after they fix the microphone issues. It's pretty new on the market and fairly priced and comparable to the ISAW EDGE. It does NOT include the accessories as it has a built-in strong magnet. I'll give it some thought if I want to wait or not.