# Action Camera with built in GPS and mature API for programatic access to metadata

Tags: video-camera, gps

I am looking for an action camera that has the following features:

- GPS built in
- All metadata (mainly GPS) needs to be accessible via an API. I need to be able to pull this metadata for any point in a video.
- At least 1080p video; the faster the framerate the better
- Needs to be mountable (I am planning on attaching this to a drone or gimbal with GoPro mounts)
- Still photos are a plus, but not required.
- Does not need an LCD
- Does not need to be waterproof

My budget for this is approximately $450.

Access to the metadata does not need to be possible while it is recording. I need to be able to access it when I am processing a video file so that I can pin point a video's recorded location on a map, or map out a route the device took on a map. This will all be done post processing.

This is similar to a previous [Action Camera question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/1463/57), but not exact. The main differences are the need for the built in GPS/metadata access and higher budget.

Answer (score -1):

One way you might be able to accomplish your goal is buying purchasing any Canon Powershot Camera, let's say... the [sx510hs](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EFILPHA) and "hack" it with [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK). You can download CHDK [here](http://mighty-hoernsche.de/). Unfortunately, most Canon Powershots mount using the "standard" 1/4" 20 thread screw.

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for, but with CHDK, you can run scripts that control the camera in LUA or BASIC on your camera.

Hope this helps! :D

Comment: Do any of the Canon Powershots have GPS built in? Also, that is a lot bigger and heavier than most action cameras, you might struggle to carry it on a drone.

Comment: @vclaw some Canon Powershots do have GPS, but not all of them.

Comment: @vclaw Some Powershots are pretty heavy, but I guess it depends a lot on what drone you're using.

Comment: This doesn't meet my criteria. It doesn't contain the GPS, which is most important to me. It is also pretty heavy. I'd also prefer not to need to mess with firmware.

Comment: @Andy Hmm... I'm pretty much out of ideas. The only other thing I can think of is RPi or Arduino with a gps and camera shield.